# dotnev environment values not loaded in other than index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to setup environment management in express js application using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package.

In my index.js file, I am getting the `.env` values properly

```
require('dotenv').config({path:__dirname+'/.env'});
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  //here i am getting values properly
   console.log("ENV",process.env.DB_NAME);
});
```

but in my another file I am getting the undefined error

`config/db.js`

```
module.exports  = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME,process.env.DB_USER,process.env.DB_PASS, {
  host: 'localhost',
  port:'3306',
  dialect: 'mysql',
  logging:false
});
```

Comment: Make sure `require('dotenv').config({path:__dirname+'/.env'});` line is above your `config/db.js` import line.

Comment: @nrgwsth its already in the top of the file